# Cómo Obtener la ruta absoluta de una imagen para pasarla al Controlador? - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Quiero obtener la ruta de la imagen para pasarla al Controlador y desde allí guardar la ruta en la base de datos MySql.

Estoy usando un `<input type="file" />` para buscar la imagen, pero claro! cuando paso el dato al controlador este tipo de `input` solo me da el nombre de la imagen y no la ruta.

¿como podría hacer? Aquí muestro visualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El .cshtml

```html
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LibroInsertado", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <br />
        <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="txt_bookName" name="txt_bookName" placeholder="Nombre de libro" required />
        <br />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nbr_lanzamiento" name="nbr_lanzamiento" min="500" max="9999" placeholder="Año de lanzamiento ej: 2019" required />
        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Autor</label>
            <select name="ddlAutor" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
                <option></option>
                @foreach (Autor item in autorList)
                {
                    <option value=@item.IdAutor>@item.Nombre</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Categoria</label>
            <select name="ddlCategory" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
                <option></option>
                @foreach (Categoria item in categoryList)
                {
                    <option value=@item.IdCategoria>@item.Nombre</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Editorial</label>
            <select name="ddlEditorial" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
                <option></option>
                @foreach (Editorial item in editorialList)
                {
                    <option value=@item.IdEditorial>@item.Nombre</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>

        <textarea name="txta_description" maxlength="300" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="40" placeholder="Descripcion del libro" required></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" value="nbr_cantidad" name="nbr_cantidad" min="1" max="10000" placeholder="Cantidad de unidades" required />
        <br />
        @*poner que acepte coma en el precio*@
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nbr_price" name="nbr_price" maxlength="10" min="1" max="500000" placeholder="Precio $" required /><br />
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="itf_urlImage" name="itf_urlImage" placeholder="Url imagen" required /><br />
        @*<input type="Text" class="form-control" id="txt_urlImage" name="txt_urlImage" maxlength="500" placeholder="Url imagen" required /><br />*@

        <input type="submit" name="btn_AgregarLibro" value="Agregar Libro" />
        <input type="reset" value="Restaurar">
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer. Solo quieres buscar la imagen, o también quieres subirla al servidor?. `<input type="file" />` sirve para **subir** imágenes o archivos al Servidor. Por otra parte, supongo que lo que quieres es la ruta de la imagen en el **cliente**, es así?

Comment: Hola Rafael Acosta gracias por contestar!, solo quiero que al buscar la imagen con el input type="file" de alguna forma poder obtener cual es la ruta de esa imagen que elegí y así poder pasarla al Controller para que me guarde la ruta en la base de datos MySql.

Comment: La ruta en tu ordenador local, sitios de red, etc?

Comment: Si obtienes la ruta completa de un archivo cargado, no podrás tener acceso a ella más tarde porque la ruta hará referencia al local. Lo ideal es que al cargar la imagen, la guardes en alguna ruta controlada por ti o similar para poder acceder cuando quieras a ella

Comment: Gracias @Paulo Urbano Rivera!  tengo una carpeta que se llama imagenes adentro de mi proyecto,mi idea es que al usar el input type="file" me abra esa carpeta imagenes que esta en mi proyecto, elegir la imagen que necesito y obtener la ruta de esa imagen.

Comment: @Claudio: Estás confundiendo las cosas.  Esa carpeta "imagenes" que está en tu proyecto, al final acabará en el servidor. no????. Entonces ya tienes la ruta .. no??

Comment: Si perdón por confundir! entonces una solución seria que yo en el controlador tenga una variable String con la url de la carpeta imagenes de mi proyecto y después haga una concatenación con el nombre de la imagen? ejemplo :  book.UrlImagen = imgUrl + Request.Form["itf_urlImage"];

Comment: @Claudio: Si algo así. Indica en la pregunta el código del Controlador donde recibes el la imagen, y te respondo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desgraciadamente lo que preguntas **no se puede** realizar de esa forma. Por cuestiones de **seguridad** los exploradores no se permite acceder al `FileSystem`.

Aun así puedes intentar hacerlo mediante **jQuery**, aunque no es seguro que funcione para todos los exploradores.

**Para IE 11:**
Puedes acceder a la información del  cuando seleccionas una imagen de esta forma:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
   console.log(this.value);
   console.log(this.files[0]);
 })
```

**Para Mozilla:**

```
 $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    console.log(this.files[0].mozFullPath);
 });
```

**Nota:** Ejemplos de prueba para el `console.log()`.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Según tus nuevos comentarios en la pregunta, la ruta necesaria sería la del **Servidor** y **NO** la del **Cliente**.

En este caso, la opción correcta para obtener el **Path completo** (absoluto) de tu imagen sería la siguiente:

```
var nombreImagen = Request.Form["itf_urlImage"];
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/principal/imagenes/"), nombreImagen);
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Dejo una lectura recomendada acerca del `<input type="file" />` en ASP.NET MVC: [Cómo subir archivos al servidor en una aplicación ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/7/30/c%C3%B3mo-subir-archivos-al-servidor-en-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-aspnet-mvc#comments)

Comment: Gracias Rafael!

Comment: igualmente utilize tu código y no se me ve la imagen cuando hago el listado de libros (todas las demas imagenes de la forma que yo lo hice anterioremente se ven todas) var nombreImagen = Request.Form["itf_urlImage"];
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/principal/imagenes/"), nombreImagen);
            //book.UrlImagen = ruta.Replace("\\", "/") + Request.Form["itf_urlImage"];
            book.UrlImagen = path;
            book.Estado = true;
            return View(book);

Comment: @Claudio: Eso ya es tema de otra pregunta. Lo importante es: ¿estás recuperando el Path absoluto de la imagen en el Servidor?

Comment: si claro el path me indica por ejemplo: Z:\carpeta1\carpeta2\ASP.NET\Librery_MVC\Librery_MVC\principal\imagenes\ContraLosZombis.jpg

Comment: @Claudio: Pues plantea una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de esta forma en el Controlador: Cree una variable `String ruta = "principal/imagenes/";` que contiene la ruta de la carpeta imagenes que tengo adentro de mi proyecto y después hago una concatenación con el nombre de la imagen que me proporciona `<input type="file" />`

Aca el Controlador

```html
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LibroInsertado()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            String ruta = "principal/imagenes/";
            Libro book = new Libro();

            book.Nombre = Request.Form["txt_bookName"];
            book.AnioDeLanzamiento = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["nbr_lanzamiento"]);
            book.IdAutor = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlAutor"]);
            book.IdCategoria = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlCategory"]);
            book.IdEditorial = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlEditorial"]);
            book.Descripcion = Request.Form["txta_description"];
            book.Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["nbr_cantidad"]);
            book.Precio = Convert.ToSingle(Request.Form["nbr_price"]);
            book.UrlImagen = ruta.Replace("\\", "/") + Request.Form["itf_urlImage"];
            book.Estado = true;
            return View(book);
        }
```

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con la solución a tu problema. Tal y como lo has resuelto, estás obteniendo el **path relativo**. Si quieres el **path absoluto** consulta mi respuesta.,

Comment: Gacias Rafael, estoy usando el servidor local que te da visual studio, entonces voy probando de manera local, seguramente vaya a tener problemas cuando en un futuro utilice otro servidor.

Comment: De la forma en la que te indico en mi respuesta, no vas a tener problemas cuando publiques tu aplicación en Producción.

Comment: Gracias Rafael muy agradecido por tu ayuda!